# Spark Structured streaming with cassandra

Tags: cassandra, spark-structured-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I am using Spark Structured streaming along with Cassandra as a sink. Snippet below:

```
  override def start(): StreamingQuery = {
    sparkContext.getSparkSession()
      .readStream
      .option("header", "false")
      .format("kafka")
      .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", bootstrapServer)
      .option("failOnDataLoss","false")
      .option("subscribe", topicName)
      .load()
      .writeStream
      .option("checkpointLocation",checkpointLocation)
      .foreachBatch(forEachFunction.arceusForEachFunction(_,_))
      .start()
```

And I am using the below to write to Cassandra inside the foreach:

```
RDD.saveToCassandra(keyspace, tableName)
```

While doing this I was wondering how to handle issues like Casssandra going down etc. Suppose, out of 3M data to be loaded, 2M was written, before an issue occurred. Now I either have to undo the 2M or process only the 1M. I am not sure what will happen is such scenarios.

Is this somehow taken care of ? Or is there something I have to write to take care of this ?

I also looked at the [spark docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch), and for "foreach batch "it says
**"depends on the implementation"**

[image]

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

First, if you use `foreachBatch` you can just write dataframe as-is, without RDD (here is [example](https://github.com/alexott/dse-playground/blob/master/spark-oss/src/main/scala/com/datastax/alexott/streaming/StructuredStreamingForEachBatch.scala#L56)):

```
      .foreachBatch((df, batchId) =>
        df.write.cassandraFormat("sttest", "test")
          .mode(SaveMode.Append).save()
      )
```

Regarding recovery - you couldn't undo write to Cassandra - it's not a transactional database, so if some data is written, then they are written. But in most cases, writes should be idempotent (except if you're using operations on lists or LWT), and you can just write data again. Spark Cassandra Connector really attempts to repeat write operation automatically, if it detects that node is down, so you should be covered by this.

P.S. New version of Spark Cassandra Connector (currently in alpha) will support native write of Spark Structured Streaming data to Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks. I need to do some manipulations to the RDD before writing, hence cannot directly write. I am using the spark cassandra connector, hence assuming the writes are idempotent, but wanted to be sure.

Comment: it doesn't matter - if you're doing some manipulations, they should be done before writing anyway...

Comment: @CSUNNY btw, SCC 2.5.0 was just released, and it has native support for spark structured streaming

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes I will be manipulating the data before writing. The only concern may be that I am planning to use Map column in Cassandra. I am not sure if these will be idempotent

Comment: Also, i am thinking of using blob instead of a map, that way it may be idempotent.

Comment: Map is idempotent. You can also use frozen map... Non idempotent is only list if you do append or prepend to it...

Comment: Great. Thanks a lot. For now then i will be using map.Also, I hope the way i have written the write  to cassandra in the question will have exactly the same result as you have mentioned in your example. I will adopt  the native support for cassandra approach, but later.

Comment: Also, the keys in the map can change i.e we can add new keys to the map. Hence frozen map may not be an option. We will be limiting no. of keys of the map though to 5

Comment: I’m not sure, if you can append to map from dataframe. In rdd you can. But it’s anyway idempotent